Sendgrid Python library - Mail send returns empty response body
Following the Sendgrid library documentation, I'd expect response to produce a response object containing the Sendgrid message id that I can then save to my own database.
However, even though the email sends as expected, and a status code of 202 is received in the response object, the response body is empty.
message = Mail(
        from_email=from_email,
        to_emails=recipients,
        subject=subject,
        plain_text_content=text_content,
        html_content=html_content
    )
    message.tracking_settings = TrackingSettings(
        open_tracking=OpenTracking(
            enable=True,
        )
    )
try:
  sg = SendGridAPIClient(api_key=sendgrid_key) 
  response = sg.send(message)
  print(response.body)
  # prints b''
  print(response.status_code)
  # prints 202


If there is no body included in the response, how are we expected to retrieve the sg_message_id needed to verify a record when receiving event webhooks. (i.e. I send a message, I want to record a log that the message was sent. I receive a webhook that a message was opened, I want my API to find the log record of that message sent, and mark the message as "opened").
